# Instead of an application, a small part of it opens

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I launch the application, in the emulator it opens as a mini window in the upper left corner, and the simulator itself becomes huge.
[image]

I do not provide the code, since this problem happens in almost all applications that I write for Android. What could be wrong here?
My colleagues have a similar problem. At first I thought it was due to a 32" monitor, but on a 13" laptop, this problem is also present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some solution to this problem. It turns out that you can fix the scaling problem when using hardware rendering by simply forcing windows to override the scaling setting.
We go along the following path:
C: \ Users \ userName \ AppData \ Local \ Android \ Sdk \ emulator \ qemu \ windows-x86_64
Go to the properties of the qemu-system-x86_64.exe file:
[image]

Select the Compatibility tab and then click on Change high DPI settings and then check the box next to and set to "Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scalling performed by:" was equal to System as in the figure below:
[image]